# How can I use gcloud dns subcommand?

Tags: dns, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dns

I'm new to Google Cloud Platform and want to use Google Cloud DNS.

I've installed `google-cloud-sdk`, but when I try using the `dns` subcommand, I get `Invalid subcommand: 'dns'`

```
$ gcloud dns managed-zone create --dns_name="example.com." \
  --description="A test zone" examplezonename
```

How can I use the `dns` subcommand? Is there a special SDK I need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [Cloud DNS documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-dns/migrating-bind-zone-command-line). You need to run:

```
gcloud components update dns
```

To be able to use DNS commands.